# Audio line-in feature

Tags: audio-recording

Does anyone know if any of the latest smartphones provide a audio line-in support? Am aware that this question has been addressed earlier as well but it has been a while since the last query on this and also the smartphones has evolved so much.

Comment: in some headphones there are 4 wires and the 4th one is for a mic so just search up on youtube how to add line input and then yeh

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completion, I will answer my own query. After googling for few days, I conclude that none of the existing Android phones in the market provide line-in support. This is more of a hardware restriction.